# Bootstrap Collapsed Nav not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi there I have a site that I am busy with and for some reason when my screen is mobile and the responsive menu shows, I click the button and the collapse menu does not push the content down. I added a height of 70px to my navbar. My question is how do I make my collapse work with the height of 70px? When i remove the navbar height of 70px it works but adds padding to the navbar at the bottom

here is my nav code:

```
<body>
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">MENU</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= base_url(); ?>">Ventech IT</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'home') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'our-services') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>our-services">SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'support') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support">IT SUPPORT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'news-and-info') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>news-and-info">KNOWLEDGE BASE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'shop') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop">SHOP ONLINE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="<?= ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'contact-us') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And my CSS for the container is as follows:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: $navigation-bg;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Make us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You still have php fragments in your code and `body` opening tag.

Comment: Collapse menu works for me. Be sure that you are including jquery before bootstrap.js, while bootstrap requires jquery, you should include it first.